# AudioMixer cant be attached to the AudioManager sounds because there no spot that says Mixer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im new to unity so dont be rude please, im new in to this all. So, i created a AudioMixer and a volumeSlider so i could drag the volumiSlider in the menu option and whenever i drag the volumeSlider it should make all the sounds that are used in the game quiter or louder. I wrote scripts and attached them to the needed GameObjects but i cant add the AudioMixer (which i called MainMixer) because there is no free spot that says "Mixer" so i could add the mixer there.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sound[] sounds;

    public static AudioManager Instance;

    public void Awake()
    {
        if(Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }


        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        foreach (Sound s in sounds)
        {
            s.source =  gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            s.source.clip = s.clip;


            s.source.volume = s.volume;
            s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
            s.source.loop = s.loop;
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        //Play("Theme");
        Play("WindTheme");

    }


    public void Play(string name)
    {
        Sound s =  Array.Find(sounds, Sound => Sound.name == name);

        if (s == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sorry sound with name not found");
            return;
        }

        s.source.Play();
    }

    public void Stop(string name)
    {
        Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, Sound => Sound.name == name);

        if (s == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sorry sound with name not found");
            return;
        }

        s.source.Stop();

        // we are here to do a
    }

}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MenuEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider volumeSlider;
    public AudioMixer mixer;

    public void SetVolume()
    {

        mixer.SetFloat("volume", volumeSlider.value);


    }


}
```

[image: volume slider]
[image: canvas]
[image: audio manager]

Comment: I hope you can see the screenshots i added in the last part because i cant open them, maybe i added them wrong

Comment: Audio mixer should be assigned at AudioSource. Then when you change the slider on the mixer that source will be influenced.

Comment: but i need to add the AudioMixer (MainMixer) first to AudioManager see on the last screenshot. But for some reason the AudioManager doesnt show any spot where i could add the AudioMixer

Comment: Why you need that?

Comment: Look here if you have time. Thats the video i watched to make it. Look at minute 11 there he  has the spots on AudioManager where he attached the AudioMixer (MainMixer) and a little earlier in the video he shows the previous steps. I did everything as he did (i think) but still i dont get the spots on AudioManager to add my AudioMixer as he did at the 11th minute of the video

[link ]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgN9ghE6qXg

Comment: It is not part of Unity, it is code that was added. And maybe yours is different.

Comment: any ideas how the code should be to do this?

Comment: You are trying to do things that are still too difficult for you. Learn the more basic stuff first and build up from there.

Comment: Hahaha, solved this. GG, nice try 

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is having a

```
 // Assign this one via Inspector
 public AudioMixerGroup audioMixerGroup;
```

and then in your loop assign it accordingly to

```
s.source.outputAudioMixerGroup = audioMixerGroup;
```